# Get events from yesterday

Tags: powershell, event-log, taskscheduler

I am trying to use PowerShell to get the results from the TaskScheduler events since yesterday. This is my code:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational  -MaxEvents 5 |
    Where-Object ($_.TimeCreated -gt [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1))
Format-List *
```

Notes:

1. The `-MaxEvents 5` is to limit output while I am developing.
2. When I remove the `Where-object` the cmdlet returns a full list. This is expected since no filtering is applied. So the error must be in the way the filtering is being done.

Comment: Your filter expression works, but your syntax is wrong. The filter expression must be in curly brackets, not parentheses: `... | Where-Object { ... } | ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FilterHashTable` property of `Get-WinEvent` to filter, it will be faster than retrieving all the events and then filtering only those you want.

This retrieves all events in the last day from the System log as I don't have any logging for TaskScheduler.

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{ LogName = "System"; StartTime = $date;}
$events | Format-List
```

You can filter on pretty much any field in the event log - [further info on this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent#-filterhashtable)